# Smartest way to grab a file from GitHub via REST API or Ocktokit (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, git, github, github-api

New Git user here, storing XML documents (each of which represents the metadata for a report) in GitHub:

```
#Repo: My-Reports

Report1
Report2
Report3
```

I need the ability to pull (not in the Git sense of the word) a single file (like Report2) from the repo to an arbitrary client. Being able to pull Report2 with a *specific tag* is a bonus.

I don't want to clone the repo to the client and do a true `git pull` as I'm not doing SCM on this box and don't want to install binaries. I just need the document, period.

I see that GitHub REST API has a Get Archive method which will download a tarball/zipball of the entire repo:

```
 GET /repos/:owner/:repo/:archive_format/:ref
```

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link

I guess I can go this route, but it will force me to manage the "document retrieval process" myself (code the task of unzipping  the archive and pulling out what I need ) I'd like to avoid that if I can....but for all I know the document is going to be compressed no matter how ask for it and I just need to live with it...like I said, Git & GitHub newb.

Is there a smarter/better way to approach this? I'll be in Ruby, so I could use the Ocktokit gem, too.

Many Thanks

Comment: You can definitely get a specific version of a file outside of the API: `https://raw.github.com/<owner>/<repo>/<tag>/<file>?login_credentials` - I'm not sure how you collect and pass in any credentials though. What is wrong with http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at `octokit` gem, I would suggest you use the `contents` method as follows (example using my own repo, and demonstrates pulling a specific tag - but any git reference can be used):

```
require 'octokit'
require 'base64'

api_response = Octokit.contents 'neilslater/games_dice', 
  :ref => 'v0.0.1', :path => 'README.md'
text_contents = Base64.decode64( api_response.content )
File.open( 'README.md', 'wb' ) { |file| file.puts text_contents }
```

This is limited to files up to 1MB max size. Note I have skipped possible issues here with character encoding - if you want to handle text_contents an memory you will need to know correct encoding to use, and apply it. When just writing the file, the simplest thing is to add the 'b' flag when opening the file.